# If $\sqrt{3}x-y<0$ , $x-\sqrt{3}y+2<0$ , $y\ge 0$, are known, how to calculate the range of $\frac{\sqrt{3}x+y}{\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}}}$.

Tags: inequality

If $\sqrt{3}x-y<0$ , $x-\sqrt{3}y+2<0$ , $y\ge 0$, are known,

how to calculate the  range of $\frac{\sqrt{3}x+y}{\sqrt{{{x}^{2}}+{{y}^{2}}}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint1: When $y=0$, it is easy to find its range. When $y\neq0$, let $k=x/y$, then it is easy to find the range of $k$, and your expression become $\frac{\sqrt{3}k+1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}}$.

Hint2: To find the range of $k$, you need to draw the graph and think of all the possible ratio $x/y$.